# SORACOM Beamの接続について

Tags: soracom

先月発表されたSORACOMを色々いじり倒そうとしているのですが､
SORACOM Beamの設定でつまずいてしまいました｡

まずはBeamへの接続確認を行おうとして､以下の状態になりました｡

**設定**

- SORACOM Beamの設定
- Beamを設定したグループへSIMをアサイン
- （念のため）SIMを停止 ⇒ 利用再開
- モバイルルーターへSORACOM SIMを乗せる
- PCを上のモバイルルータに接続

**状態**

- インターネットには繋がる(普通にネットも見れる)
- `ping www.google.co.jp` ⇒ 繋がる
- `ping beam.soracom.io` ⇒ `ping: sendto: Host is down`
- `curl http://beam.soracom.io:8888/`
  ⇒ `curl: (7) Failed to connect to beam.soracom.io port 8888: Operation timed out`

というような状況です｡
どうにもbeam.soracom.ioに繋がらないような状況で､どなたか助けになる情報持っていたら教えて下さい｡

**環境**

OS: Mac OS X YOSEMITE
SIM: ナノ データ通信/SMS
ルーター: Docomo BF-01B
です｡

Answer (score 2):

`beam.soracom.io`はリンクローカルアドレス(`169.254.254.169`)に紐付いているので、リンクローカルアドレスのルーティング設定をご確認ください。
今回はWi-Fiルーター経由とのことですので、OS XのルーティングとWi-Fiルーターのルーティングそれぞれが関係します。同機種別型番のDWR-PGの設定例をスライドにまとめているのでP.14〜P.16の辺りを参考にしてください。

- [ぼくのかんがえたさいきょうの SORACOM Beam検証環境 // Speaker Deck](https://speakerdeck.com/takipone/bokufalsekangaetasaikiyoufalse-soracom-beamjian-zheng-huan-jing)

Comment: お､お､おー
ありがとうございます
試してみます!!

Comment: うまく接続できました!!
ありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Comment: 繋がってよかったです。Beam、使い倒していきましょう！